# How do I resolve red filenames with Android if I can't find any issues?

Tags: android, filenames

**Problem:** I cannot seem to resolve the red filenames within my project despite doing the common fixes.

**What I was trying to do:** I had existing functionality in another project, as in one `class` and one `activity`, that I copied to this project rather than recreating them.

**What I have tried:** I have fixed some issues and warnings that were identified or apparent. I included the new activity in the `androidmanifest.xml`, corrected `import` and `package` statements, etc. I continued with searching here and elsewhere. I tried suggestions such as, invalidating caches and restarting, running an analysis on each file for errors or issues, and simply committed to git (VCS). Some similar posting went unresolved like on JetBrains, which the first response was to commit to VCS. Some suggestions were to make changes in `Settings` but I really felt that was a workaround and not a solution.

[image: Red Filenames]

**activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivityMaster">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/master_enter_db" />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/database_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/master_enter_db"
            android:hint="@string/master_enter_db"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="">
    </EditText>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/addDatabase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/master_add_db">
    </Button>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/database_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/useSelectedDatabase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/master_no_db_selected"
            android:clickable="false"
    >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Class**

public class MainActivityMaster extends AppCompatActivity {

```
MasterDatabase mMasterDB;
MasterDao mMasterDBDao;
EditText mDBToAdd;
Button mAddDB,mUseSelectedDatabase;
ListView mDatabaseList;
SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
Cursor mCsr;
long mSelectedDatabaseId = 0;
String mSelectedDatabaseName = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_master);
    mDBToAdd = this.findViewById(R.id.database_name);
    mAddDB = this.findViewById(R.id.addDatabase);
    mUseSelectedDatabase = this.findViewById(R.id.useSelectedDatabase);
    mDatabaseList = this.findViewById(R.id.database_list);

    mMasterDB = MasterDatabase.getInstance(this);
    mMasterDBDao = mMasterDB.getMasterDao();


    setUpAddDBButton();
    setUpUseSelectedDatabaseButton();
    setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
}

private void setUpAddDBButton() {
    mAddDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mDBToAdd.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                if (mMasterDBDao.insert(new MasterDatabaseList(mDBToAdd.getText().toString())) > 0) {
                    mDBToAdd.setText("");
                    setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setUpUseSelectedDatabaseButton() {
    mUseSelectedDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mSelectedDatabaseId > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASEID, mSelectedDatabaseId);
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_DATABASENAME,mSelectedDatabaseName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setOrRefreshDatabaseList() {
    mCsr = mMasterDBDao.getAllDatabasesAsCursor();
    if (mSCA == null) {
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mCsr,
                new String[]{MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );
        mDatabaseList.setAdapter(mSCA);
        mDatabaseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            /* Handle Clicking on an Item (i.e. prepare UseSelected Button) */
            @SuppressLint("Range")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mSelectedDatabaseId = l;
                if (l > 0) {
                    mSelectedDatabaseName = mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(MasterDatabaseList.COL_DATABASE_NAME));
                    mUseSelectedDatabase.setText(mSelectedDatabaseName);
                    mUseSelectedDatabase.setClickable(true);
                } else {
                    mUseSelectedDatabase.setText(R.string.master_no_db_selected);
                    mUseSelectedDatabase.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setOrRefreshDatabaseList();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCsr.close();
}
```

}

Comment: *Problem: I cannot seem to resolve the red filenames within my project despite doing the common fixes.* So what exactly is your problem? What does the IDE tell you to fix?

Comment: @Prince Ali - Thanks for responding. I stated it in the first sentence you quoted, the IDE is indicating through Red Filenames there is an issue with those files. That is how the IDE default is intended and setup. Red filenames indicate an issue. JetBrains states "It means that those files are not added to the git repository (not committed nor staged)", which I have tried. In the past when this occurred importing a separate project file that the package reference needed updated. The only suggestions outside of those are to change the color indicators in the IDE which isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue and it was probably due to being naive on my part. The files were not being committed because they were not showing as "checked" to be committed. The one caveat to this scenario is that I had never encountered it before because all files I wanted to commit were checked by default, so I didn't see it before. Once I check the box, it committed since there were not other possible "red-filename" issues.

[image: Red-Filename-Checkbox]